# Multidimensional Associative Array Output

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am using PHP / Codeigniter and working with [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), I am trying to output some data from a multidimensional array.

In my **controller** I have;

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MyKey");
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);

$data = array(
    'title' => 'Library Items',
    'gbook' => $service->volumes->listVolumes('0-7515-3831-0')
);
```

In my **view** I have;

```
  echo 'Page Title is: ' .$title; // this successfully prints 'Library Items'
  echo 'Book Title is: '; // need to output the book title here 
  echo 'Description is: '; // need to output the book description here
```

When I `print_r($gbook)` in my view I see the following https://pastebin.com/HM5hds6e

I'm not sure how to select specific values from this array (namely `title` and `isbn`). Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a single book or a list of books? Because `$service->volumes->listVolumes('Harry Potter')` returns a *Google_Service_Books_Volumes* object containing all volumes matching 'Harry Potter', it's not a single volume/book.

Comment: Please refer the code in my answer and see if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

As I have checked in this url https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client you can directly loop that variable `gbook`

Loop the items array `$gbook` from the response and get the details of books

```
foreach ($gbook as $bookInfo) {
  echo "Book title : ".$bookInfo["volumeInfo"]["title"];
  $bookIdent = array_map(function($v){
    return $v["identifier"];
  }, $bookInfo["volumeInfo"]["industryIdentifiers"]);
  echo "Book ISBN : ".(implode(",", $bookIdent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the volume data like this:

```
echo 'Page Title is: ' .$title; // this successfully prints 'Library Items'
echo 'Book Title is: ' .$gbook->getItems()[0]['volumeInfo']['title'];
echo 'Description is: ' .$gbook->getItems()[0]['volumeInfo']['description'];
```